# Odata: Mapping View Model to Domain Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, odata, viewmodel

I have an odata call that works properly the first time but fails during any successive call due to properties not matching. My controller has very little logic as it's just responsible for calling my domain service to query an Entity Framework database and returning the results as view models. However, when I try to sort I get an error because the hierarchy of my view model does not match my domain model.

Domain Model:

```
public class Parent
{
  public object Child
  {
    public string Name
  }
}
```

View Model:

```
public class Parent
{
  public string ChildName
}
```

Using the above examples the EF query would return a list of Parents, which I would convert to view models to send off to the client. When a sort request is made on ChildName odata fails because Parent has no concept of ChildName. I need to map ChildName to Child.Name. I've seen examples of people using EntitySets to change the name but none that will map the model in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using EF to convert my domain model to a view model using a LINQ expression during the query. Example but changed the view model to ParentView and added constructor:

```
var query = from p in context.Parent select new ParentView(p.Child.Name)
```

The positive of this is that it's all run on the database so I'm not transporting unnecessary data. Also, I am able to continue to use the odata options in the query since odata will add onto the query. However, I can't help but feel this is not the best way.